# Making text colour inverted to background-colour css proprety for smooth transitions

Tags: html, css

I've got this thing right now where I've got this sliding background on hover, and I find it a bit janky that all of the text changes colour at the same time. Can I somehow make it so that only the parts over the black background change colour?

```css
a.nav {
    font-family: Manrope;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 1px, #000 1px);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: right;
    background-size: 0%;
    transition: background-size .15s;
}
a.nav:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position-x: left;
}
```

```html
<a class="nav">About us</a>
```

**THANK YOU!!**

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use the `background-clip:text` property. (I've modified the linear-gradient to ensure there's no transparent region which doesn't work with background-clip.) The drawback is in the html you would need to wrap the text into a span:

```css
.nav {
  font-family: Manrope;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, white 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: right;
  transition: background-position 0.5s;
}

.nav>span {
  background: inherit;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  filter: invert(1);
  -webkit-filter: invert(1);
}

.nav:hover {
  background-position: left;
}
```

```html
<a class="nav"><span>About us</span></a>
```

---

#### Edit

Just noticed that your background is entering from the left but exiting from the right. In this case you could keep your original effect while adding `background-color: white;` instead of using the modified `linear-gradient` provided above.

```css
.nav {
  font-family: Manrope;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Add this to prevent transparent background,
     you could use 'inherit' instead if parent has defined background-color*/
  background-color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 1px, #000 1px);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-x: right;
  background-size: 0% 100%;
  transition: background-size 0.5s;
}

.nav:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position-x: left;
}

.nav>span {
  background: inherit;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  filter: invert(1);
  -webkit-filter: invert(1);
}
```

```html
<a class="nav"><span>About us</span></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got half the solution posting here to help someone find the remaining :) !

```css
a.nav {
position: relative;
  font-family: Manrope;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

a.nav:after {
  content: 'About us';
  font-family: Manrope;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 1px, #000 1px);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-x: right;
  background-size: 100%;
  visibility:hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width:0px;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  transition: all 2s;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
}

a.nav:hover:after {
  visibility:visible;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<a class="nav">About us</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to have it done with only color, then another solution is by using the CSS [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) to create an opposite color based on the text color and the background color. The only catch here is that different colors do get different results. Using black on white will be the most predictable.

```css
a.nav {
  font-family: Manrope;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
  background: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 1px, #000 1px);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-x: left;
  background-size: 0%;
  transition: background 200ms ease-in-out;
}

a.nav:hover {
  background-size: 100%;
}

a.nav .nav-label {
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<a class="nav">
  <span class="nav-label">About us</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

The trick is to *create the illusion* that the colors are changing. A way to do this is by overlapping two *almost* identical elements with the same label and use CSS [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path).

In the example below there are two elements both with the same text but with different text and background colors. The duplicate element has the [`aria-hidden="true"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-hidden) to let accessibility technologies - like screen readers - know that they should ignore this text. The top layer is clipped out by default and unclipped on hover.

```css
a.nav {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template: 1 / 1;
  font-family: Manrope;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.nav :is(.nav-item, .nav-negative) {
  grid-area: 1 / 1;
  padding: 5px;
}

a.nav .nav-item {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

a.nav .nav-negative {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, 0% 100%);
  transition: clip-path 200ms ease-in-out;
}

a.nav:hover .nav-negative  {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<a class="nav">
  <span class="nav-item">About us</span>
  <span class="nav-negative" aria-hidden="true">About us</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score -3):

I came with a different sollution.

```css
.text-one,
.text-two {
  font-family: Manrope;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.text-two {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: black;
  transition: width .5s ease;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.text-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.text-container:hover .text-two {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-container">
  <div class="text-one">SOME WORD HERE</div>
  <div class="text-two">SOME WORD HERE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).